# Youtube Video download php script

Tags: php, video, youtube

I am trying find solution to get direct video URL for youtube videos. But i am not able to find any solution.

I am currenlty using [Youtubedownloader](https://github.com/jeckman/YouTube-Downloader/) 
.When i click on download video it generates link to video but its not actually recognized as download link in my web application. I am trying to upload remote video with this url but it says no video found in my web application.

currently its generating links like this.

```
https://r3---sn-25glen7y.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?mm=31&mn=sn-25glen7y&key=yt6&signature=51F3C4BA56C96FE593901AD0D28FBA8ED477B287.4A15A870692675DDFBC94819EAEB59C9D8DB4141&mt=1495042064&pcm2=yes&mv=m&ei=X4gcWfiiHJCMcJHqmIAO&pl=16&ms=au&sparams=dur%2Cei%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpcm2%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cusequic%2Cexpire&usequic=no&mime=video%2Fmp4&upn=ZMkz0gtqWNk&expire=1495063743&initcwndbps=11898750&ratebypass=yes&ipbits=0&lmt=1472845289256331&itag=22&requiressl=yes&ip=62.210.149.105&source=youtube&dur=243.623&id=o-APOPZz5wo1XWIE0Wyq_veLdgBGr1xgALdohBIGIJRggx&title=How-Does-it-Grow-Cauliflower
```

What i need to have links generated in "filename.mp4" or "filename.webem" format Is it possible?

Comment: It's most likely possible. However, what makes you think we would help you do something that the website doesn't normally allow you to do? If you create a website with copyright material you own, and you do everything within you power to prevent ppl from stealing it, how would like it if we would create something to steal it anyway?

Comment: There is a need in project. And thats the reason i have to add in my script. About copyright issues, copyright content is violated when you dont provide a credit. But when i have to provide feature to import channel for user of youtube without any hassle, they can do it with this script just adding link. and uploads video to their account. It saves their time, instead of fatching their old files and get full channel on new platform.

Comment: Just because your reasons are honerable, doesn't mean your users are. Fact is: Youtube doesn't provide the feature. You want the feature? Request it in the Youtube API. But that's just my opinion. Maybe you're lucky and someone here doesn't have the same moral standards as me and helps you out.

Comment: Why are you even replying ? If you dont want to help or anything to do with it? If you are wise enough you shouldn't have to answer even at first place.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the function in detail, try this [Simple YouTube downloader](https://github.com/rintoug/Simple-YouTube-Downloader)

This repo consists of 3 files, which include a form and downloader class in the most simple way to understand.